# Why does subscribe not executed in a new thread?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I have task like this:

```
Observable.just(getMessagesFromDb()).
    subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).
    observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
    subscribe(incomingMessages -> {
    //do something
    });
```

where `getMessagesFromDb` is method *synchronously* getting messages, without multithreading inside. According to the RxAndroid documentation for subscribeOn method:

> Asynchronously subscribes Observers to this Observable on the specified Scheduler

And there is my question - why is the database request executed on main thread? How to do it asynchronously?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen method chaining with the dot at the end before.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What you see below is a slightly modified version of your code with `getMessagesFromDb()` called to assign a return value to a variable:

```
 Object data = getMessagesFromDb();
 Observable.just(data).
    subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).
    observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
    subscribe(incomingMessages -> {
      //do something
    });
```

It's exactly how `Observable.just` works, and `getMessagesFromDb()` is indeed called in the main thread (as you're calling it in the main thread).

You have to defer it using `Observable.fromCallable` method as follows:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> getMessageFromDb()).
           subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).
           observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
           subscribe(incomingMessages -> {
              //do something
           });
```

Please note that you can use `Observable.defer` instead of `Observable.fromCallable`, but it's a little bit more complicated :

```
Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(getMessageFromDb()))
```

The previous version of this response use `Observable.create`. But it is complicated to build an Observable with this method. Try to always prefer `Observable.defer` or `Observable.fromCallable`

Comment: You can also: `Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(getMessagesFromDb()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()))`

Comment: A detailed and thorough explanation that helped more than just for this one example.

Comment: This example indeed explained really well the concept and usage case of defer and just operator. Thanks for much for this.

Comment: How you would do this in RxJava2? Calling defer or fromCallable won't execute unless you call subscribe on it effectively converting the type to a Disposable. What if i want to have a Observable/Flowable.